# JavaFX save method for two files

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX application where the user through a series of textfields and dropdown menus has to create some sort of report. The data from the user are written in an .xml file, I also convert the .xml file to HTML and display it with the `Webview` class.

The following code is the save method I use to help the user save her work in the desired directory. It is supposed to save both the .xml and the html file which it does very well.

```
/**
 * Method to save both xml and html file to desired location by the user
 */
@FXML
public void handleSave(){
    isSaved = true;

    try {
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        // Set extension filter
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

        // Show save file dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
        String fileLoc = file.getAbsolutePath();

        if (file != null) {
            // Make sure it has the correct extension
            if (!file.getPath().endsWith(".xml")) {
                System.out.println("Adding the extension");
                file = new File(file.getPath() + ".xml");
            }

            // creates the xml elements and writes them to the argument file
            xmlFromObjects(file);
            this.setXMLFileName(file.getAbsolutePath());

        }

        // convert the xml to html
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        javax.xml.transform.Source xslDoc = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/lib/report.xsl"));
        javax.xml.transform.Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource(file);
        OutputStream html = new FileOutputStream(htmlFile);
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
        transformer.transform(xmlDoc, new StreamResult(html));

        // the following happens if saved file has .xml extension
        int pos = fileLoc.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos > 0){
            // want to get the name of the saved xml file
            fileLoc = fileLoc.substring(0, pos);

            // moves the local html file to the location the xml file is
            htmlFile.renameTo(new File(fileLoc + ".html"));
            this.setHtmlFile(fileLoc + ".html");
        }else{
            htmlFile.renameTo(new File(fileLoc + ".html"));
            this.setHtmlFile(fileLoc + ".html");

        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would like to know if my code can become better than it currently is, in terms of efficiency or modularity. Basically, feel free to judge my code.